# Why can Tampermonkey's GM_xmlhttpRequest perform a CORS request?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cors, tampermonkey

[GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest) can perform an ajax call that ignores the same origin policy.
I have checked the network panel in Chrome but I cannot find the XHR from GM_xmlhttpRequest in it. It just works.
I'd like to know what exactly happened and the reason why it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tampermonkey can do cross-origin ajax because it is an extension and extensions are trusted much more than some website's javascript.  See ["Referencing external resources" in the Chrome extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external).

Tampermonkey scripts operate in a privileged scope and `GM_xmlhttpRequest` was created specifically to wrap around a privileged `XMLHttpRequest` call.

To see the Tampermonkey XHR, you must [inspect Tampermonkey's background page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10257301/331508). You will see the userscript's XHR In the network panel there.